# Messages not sent to DLQ topic

Tags: avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, dead-letter

I want to use DLQ for Exceptions

Here is application.yml
Topic is created successfully but i am not getting the exception message in my DLQ topic

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers:
            - localhost:9092
          consumer-properties:
            key.deserializer : org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
            specific.avro.reader: true
            enable.auto.commit: true
        bindings:
          resourceInventoryInput:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: true
              autoCommitOnError: true
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: dead-out
              dlqProducerProperties:
                configuration:
                  key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                  value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      bindings:
        resourceInventoryInput:
          binder: kafka
          destination: ${application.messaging.topic}
          content-type: application/*+avro
          group: ${application.messaging.group}
      default-binder: kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask the same question in multiple places; it's a waste of your time and ours.

I already answered you [on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/918).

I just tested your yaml with Boot 2.1.15 and Greenwich.SR6 (and Boot 2.2.8/Hoxton.SR5) and it works just fine. The only changes I made was to change the binding name to input and comment out the avro stuff.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Kbgh9181Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Kbgh9181Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {
        throw new RuntimeException("foo");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "kbgh918", topics = "dead-out", properties = "auto.offset.reset:earliest")
    public void listen(Message<?> in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

> GenericMessage [payload=byte[3], headers={x-original-offset=[B@67917b81, x-original-partition=[B@467895cd, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedTopic=dead-out, kafka_offset=5, x-exception-message=[B@51def01e, x-exception-fqcn=[B@531d42e5, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3fbc6674, x-original-topic=[B@3d684ab3, x-original-timestamp-type=[B@1b101300, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, x-original-timestamp=[B@222370ed, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1592402977606, x-exception-stacktrace=[B@7e703d1b}]